# How to exorcise squirrels?

Tags: garage, pest-control

We have (at least) one squirrel abiding under the roof of the garage, and we'd like to get rid of it (them) before it gets really cold.

I installed a sound-generating "anti-pest" device in there two days ago -- and someone saw one critter getting out, but it was not clear, if he was taking his stuff with him, or was planning to return. Besides, the sound makes it uncomfortable to be there even for humans -- and cannot be a *permanent* solution.

How does one get rid of squirrels -- without killing them (I have a weakness for fellow mammals)?

Comment: **How to exorcise a squirrel**. Get a Hamster cage, it is round and on an axle. The squirrel gets inside the cage and runs causing the cage to go round and round. The faster the squirrel goes the more **exorcise** it gets. *This has been today's "fun with words"*

Comment: Funny , the best way is to move. I love squires but have had to kill a few in my lifetime. For some reason I had a few that ate there way through exterior siding sheeting and into my attic. Sealed several times but I eventually installed a high voltage grid 1000v at a low current a week or so later found the bugger but still had 1/2 a dozen that would get the non salted peanuts, some would take them from my hand and my daughter still feeds them don’t know why that one did so much damage.